# Google App Engine background thread vs. task

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

What is the difference between creating a thread in the background and creating a task for it?

For example, with a thread:

```
tid = background_thread.start_new_background_thread(f, ["foo", "bar"])
```

And then with a task:

```
taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'key': key})
```

What are the differences? When would one be used over the other? Are there any advantages of using the taskqueue over the background_thread (which seems easier to set up)?

Comment: there's quite a low limit on the number of simultaneous background threads that can be run. Whereas with tasks, well, check your task quota on the dashboard.

Comment: A background thread will only run as long as the instance that it is running on is around, and the life time of the request or task, unless you use a managed vm.  A thread spawned from a front facing request can only live for 60 secs or until the request is complete which ever is first. A background thread on a task can only last for the life of the task or 10mins which ever is first.  Before managed VM's there was no way to any particular thread for longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest difference is that tasks run independently of any other code, you can easily manage their processing speed, they can be automatically retried when they fail, and you can set them up with different options, like ETA.

You can do all of that on your own, of course, but you will have to write and test a lot of code.